# How to remove and combine appengine indexes?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a kind which is using a lot of write ops that I'd like to optimize.

The SDK generated the following indexes:

```
    - kind: Prefix
      properties:
      - name: deleted_in
      - name: hostkey
      - name: list_name
      - name: added_in

    - kind: Prefix
      properties:
      - name: list_name
      - name: added_in

    - kind: Prefix
      properties:
      - name: list_name
      - name: deleted_in
```

It seems like it should be possible to combine at least two of those by changing the order of the first index. However, doing so results in an error for a missing index.

This surprises me because the first index is not in the order of the query filters or the order of the kind. My query would work fine in any given order.

```
query(
            Prefix.list_name == lst,
            Prefix.hostkey == hostkey,
            Prefix.deleted_in == None,
            Prefix.added_in > None,
        )
```

Another possible way to save on indexing would to turn off some of the automatic single-property indexes. Is it possible to have a property with `indexed=False` that is included in a composite index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a query it can either be satisfied by a single composite index or it will use multiple indexes and use the [zigzag merge join algorithm](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/next-gen-queries-appengine.html).

The first index you listed is the single index that answers your query. First the index has to specify all of the equality filters, then it has to specify the inequality filter / orders. As you mentioned, the order of the equality filters doesn't matter, they just have to appear before the inequality (or orders). In order for zigzag merge join to work, all the indexes must satisfy the inequality filter / orders. So in order to use merge join for your query, you'd have to use indexes that all had added_in as the last property. Here is an example of a set of indexes you could use:

```
- kind: Prefix
  properties:
  - name: list_name
  - name: added_in

- kind: Prefix
  properties:
  - name: hostkey
  - name: added_in

- kind: Prefix
  properties:
  - name: deleted_in
  - name: added_in
```

Since you already have an index on (list_name, added_in), you could add another index:

```
- kind: Prefix
  properties:
  - name: hostkey
  - name: deleted_in
  - name: added_in
```

When this is combined with your existing index on (list_name, added_in), it can answer your query.

However as you found, you cannot use the other two indexes to answer your query. The reason for this is that your index on (list_name, deleted_in) does not have your inequality property on the index.

[Here is a good reference page.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection)

To answer your second question: No, it is not possible to turn off single-property indexes while still having the property in a composite index. See [this issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4231) for discussion on it.